External partitions not visible in VMware Fusion Ubuntu Server 24.04 (arm64) virtual machine
Just installed VM Fusion Pro for personal use on my M1 MacBookPro. Created two virtual machines: (1) Windows 11 Pro and (2) Ubuntu Server 24.04. I can’t see partitions on external disk despite USB device chain being explicitly being attached to the active virtual machine (I’ve tried both)
To keep things simple, requesting support troubleshooting mounting ext4 partitions in the Ubuntu Server virtual machine. I suspect when we figure this out, the Windows virtual machine will resolve itself.
When my Ubuntu Server virtual machine is active, I successfully get the following dialog box for each of the 4 devices in the USB-C hub (card reader, USB, ethernet, USB-C PD) when I plug in the drive. I click "Connect to Linux" each time:

I'm clear the Linux virtual machine sees something as lsblk output differs before and after (notice the disk is acknowledged (don’t know why there are two) and partitions are missing from /dev/sda and /dev/sdb):

Any ideas on what might be happening and how I might be able to resolve this issue?
For the record: the drive is a Seagate 6TB HDD - it mounts fine (through the same USB-C hub) in both macOS Sonoma (14.5) and Asahi Linux (Fedora KDE). The drive also mounts fine in several other Linux distros on Intel-based hosts. There is a mix of FAT32, NTFS, APFS, and ext4 partitions. Partition table is GPT only.
